# zero of $\frac{\sin(x t)}{x} - \frac{\sin(y t)}{y}$ for fixed $x$ and $y$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $x$ and $y$ be fixed nonzero real numbers. I want to show that
$$
\frac{\sin(x t)}{x} - \frac{\sin(y t)}{y}
$$
has infinitely many zeros for any choice of $x$ and $y$.
I have tried looking into some examples and it seems to be the case.
Is there a simple way to show this? thank u!

Comment: If $x/y$ is rational, then just plug $t=\pi n/x$; then for infinitely many positive integer $n$ both summands equal zero. If $x/y$ is irrational, then you still can plug $t=\pi n/x$ and find infinitely many positive and negative values of your function.

Comment: true... thank you!